# Can I up-vote my own question?

Tags: support, voting, up-votes

So I am new to this site and I hope this is a proper forum to ask this - if not please do not punish me too harshly. I must seem like a narcissist to inquire - but I posted a question that has +6 up-votes for two answers but no one thinks the question itself is worth an up-vote. I probably won't do it even if I can but it is a bit weird that there can be very good answers to a blah question.

Comment: Of course you can have good answers to questions that aren't deemed good: I for instance rarely upvote questions that I deem pretty simple and not really interesting, but I might upvote an answer if it conveys the principles involved in a clear way.

Comment: By the way, meta (this site you're reading this on right now) is definitely the right place to ask questions about the site itself, and we definitely encourage you to do so. Off the top of my head, the only thing you shouldn't ask about is individual suspensions (out of respect for the privacy of the suspended user, and for other reasons), and even then, you probably won't get _punished_ for asking, you'll probably just get advised not to do that, and the question might be closed or deleted. Asking about the process of suspension in general is totally fine.

Comment: Nevertheless,  at this point, do you think I should consider closing  this question? Would you if you were me?

Comment: Well, users don't actually have the ability to close their own questions. So it's a moot point. (But even if you could, I would not advise doing so.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go ahead, try it. The site will tell you that's not possible.

(I do think that there may occasionally be very good answers to a blah question; some answerers manage to [cook soup from a stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Soup)).

Answer (score 3):

The system will not let you cast a vote for a post created by the same user.

And though we know that most people can be counted on to understand this let me put the policy on sock-puppetry down, just for the record:

- Using sock-puppet accounts to vote for yourself is forbidden, and moderators have access to tool for detecting such behavior which can lead to suspension from the site and deletion of secondary account(s).

Comment: I said I probably would not even if I could. I actually have a life.  I may be a narcissist but I am not a miscreant

Comment: John, sorry if my short tone came across as accusatory. I'm busy in 'real' life just now and was rushing through a check on Physics before getting back to work. I wanted the official position on sock-puppetry down in black and white (again) because we have a background level of cheating attempts like that.

Comment: thanks, can I un-flag you?

Comment: I don't think so, but some other moderator will be along to clear it eventually.